# Ace editor json with handlebar syntax

Tags: json, syntax, handlebars.js, editor, ace-editor

Ace can either highlight syntax for JSON or handlebar, but not at the same time.

I'm using ace editor with "handlebar" mode for a web ide.

```
editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/handlebar');
```

It works as intended. However, when ace is set to mode 'handlebar', no syntax displays for the json,
so it looks really ugly and error detection is really difficult.

If I set the ace editor mode to

```
editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/json');
```

Ace editor displays errors due to the handlebar code syntax in the json.
For example, `{{#each data.content.people}}` is handlebar syntax, and so if ace editor is set to mode 'json', it will display an error at that line.

example json:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "NAMES",
        "values": [
          {{#each data.content.people}}
          {
            "name": {
              "value": "{{{this}}}",
              "synonyms": [
                "{{{lowerCase this}}}"
              ]
            }
          }{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}
          {{/each}}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way for Ace editor to have syntax detection for both json and handlebar at the same time without having to create a custom mode?

Comment: there is a `mode` for `handlebars` (maybe recently added).  You won't get JSON syntax highlighting but it will show the templating alot cleaner